# Apache Nifi's PutS3Object throwing PKIX path building error even after adding the AWS certificate to the Truststore

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-nifi

I installed JDK 17 and set JAVA_HOME to it.

Apache Nifi Version : 1.15.3

I tried to set the following data flow with the following processors: QueryDatabaseTable -> ConvertAvroToParquet -> PutS3Object

I got the following error at PutS3Object when uploading the file:

```
2022-02-17 19:40:59,374 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-4] o.a.nifi.processors.aws.s3.PutS3Object PutS3Object[id=d92f4ad3-017e-1000-449a-57a3038b73a7] Error checking S3 Multipart Upload list for bucket-name: Unable to execute HTTP request: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
2022-02-17 19:41:00,181 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-4] o.a.nifi.processors.aws.s3.PutS3Object PutS3Object[id=d92f4ad3-017e-1000-449a-57a3038b73a7] Failed to put StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=889e2e83-5704-4538-ba1d-5e6d9bf4e74d,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1645102244327-1, container=default, section=1], offset=492, length=1129],offset=0,name=889e2e83-5704-4538-ba1d-5e6d9bf4e74d.parquet,size=1129] to Amazon S3 due to com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
? causes: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
? causes: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
? causes: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I went to AWS S3 'bucket-name' web page. Clicked in the browser's certificate button right next to URL in Google Chrome. Exported it with both Base64 and DER with different names.

I used the following command to add the certificate to the truststore

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2\lib\security\cacerts." -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias AWS -file aws_nw.crt
```

I restarted my PC. I started nifi and ran the processor but I got the same error anyway.

```
PutS3Object XML configuration:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<template encoding-version="1.3">
    <description></description>
    <groupId>201192b8-017f-1000-194e-6c771b73e759</groupId>
    <name>puts3</name>
    <snippet>
        <processors>
            <id>3399e3ad-a008-305c-0000-000000000000</id>
            <parentGroupId>ce22d309-6255-3d86-0000-000000000000</parentGroupId>
            <position>
                <x>0.0</x>
                <y>0.0</y>
            </position>
            <bundle>
                <artifact>nifi-aws-nar</artifact>
                <group>org.apache.nifi</group>
                <version>1.15.3</version>
            </bundle>
            <config>
                <bulletinLevel>WARN</bulletinLevel>
                <comments></comments>
                <concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount>1</concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount>
                <descriptors>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Object Key</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>Object Key</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Bucket</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>Bucket</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Content Type</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>Content Type</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Content Disposition</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>Content Disposition</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Cache Control</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>Cache Control</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Access Key</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>Access Key</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Secret Key</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>Secret Key</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Credentials File</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>Credentials File</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>AWS Credentials Provider service</key>
                        <value>
                            <identifiesControllerService>org.apache.nifi.processors.aws.credentials.provider.service.AWSCredentialsProviderService</identifiesControllerService>
                            <name>AWS Credentials Provider service</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>s3-object-tags-prefix</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>s3-object-tags-prefix</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>s3-object-remove-tags-prefix</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>s3-object-remove-tags-prefix</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Storage Class</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>Storage Class</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Region</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>Region</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Communications Timeout</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>Communications Timeout</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Expiration Time Rule</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>Expiration Time Rule</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>FullControl User List</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>FullControl User List</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Read Permission User List</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>Read Permission User List</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Write Permission User List</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>Write Permission User List</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Read ACL User List</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>Read ACL User List</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Write ACL User List</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>Write ACL User List</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Owner</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>Owner</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>canned-acl</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>canned-acl</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>SSL Context Service</key>
                        <value>
                            <identifiesControllerService>org.apache.nifi.ssl.SSLContextService</identifiesControllerService>
                            <name>SSL Context Service</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Endpoint Override URL</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>Endpoint Override URL</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Signer Override</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>Signer Override</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Multipart Threshold</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>Multipart Threshold</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Multipart Part Size</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>Multipart Part Size</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Multipart Upload AgeOff Interval</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>Multipart Upload AgeOff Interval</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Multipart Upload Max Age Threshold</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>Multipart Upload Max Age Threshold</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>s3-temporary-directory-multipart</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>s3-temporary-directory-multipart</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>server-side-encryption</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>server-side-encryption</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>encryption-service</key>
                        <value>
                            <identifiesControllerService>org.apache.nifi.processors.aws.s3.AmazonS3EncryptionService</identifiesControllerService>
                            <name>encryption-service</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>use-chunked-encoding</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>use-chunked-encoding</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>use-path-style-access</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>use-path-style-access</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>proxy-configuration-service</key>
                        <value>
                            <identifiesControllerService>org.apache.nifi.proxy.ProxyConfigurationService</identifiesControllerService>
                            <name>proxy-configuration-service</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Proxy Host</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>Proxy Host</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Proxy Host Port</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>Proxy Host Port</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>proxy-user-name</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>proxy-user-name</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>proxy-user-password</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>proxy-user-password</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                </descriptors>
                <executionNode>ALL</executionNode>
                <lossTolerant>false</lossTolerant>
                <penaltyDuration>30 sec</penaltyDuration>
                <properties>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Object Key</key>
                        <value>${filename}</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Bucket</key>
                        <value>s3-bucket-name</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Content Type</key>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Content Disposition</key>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Cache Control</key>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Access Key</key>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Secret Key</key>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Credentials File</key>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>AWS Credentials Provider service</key>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>s3-object-tags-prefix</key>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>s3-object-remove-tags-prefix</key>
                        <value>false</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Storage Class</key>
                        <value>Standard</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Region</key>
                        <value>us-west-1</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Communications Timeout</key>
                        <value>30 secs</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Expiration Time Rule</key>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>FullControl User List</key>
                        <value>${s3.permissions.full.users}</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Read Permission User List</key>
                        <value>${s3.permissions.read.users}</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Write Permission User List</key>
                        <value>${s3.permissions.write.users}</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Read ACL User List</key>
                        <value>${s3.permissions.readacl.users}</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Write ACL User List</key>
                        <value>${s3.permissions.writeacl.users}</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Owner</key>
                        <value>${s3.owner}</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>canned-acl</key>
                        <value>${s3.permissions.cannedacl}</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>SSL Context Service</key>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Endpoint Override URL</key>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Signer Override</key>
                        <value>Default Signature</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Multipart Threshold</key>
                        <value>5 GB</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Multipart Part Size</key>
                        <value>5 GB</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Multipart Upload AgeOff Interval</key>
                        <value>60 min</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Multipart Upload Max Age Threshold</key>
                        <value>7 days</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>s3-temporary-directory-multipart</key>
                        <value>${java.io.tmpdir}</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>server-side-encryption</key>
                        <value>None</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>encryption-service</key>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>use-chunked-encoding</key>
                        <value>true</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>use-path-style-access</key>
                        <value>false</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>proxy-configuration-service</key>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Proxy Host</key>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Proxy Host Port</key>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>proxy-user-name</key>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>proxy-user-password</key>
                    </entry>
                </properties>
                <runDurationMillis>0</runDurationMillis>
                <schedulingPeriod>0 sec</schedulingPeriod>
                <schedulingStrategy>TIMER_DRIVEN</schedulingStrategy>
                <yieldDuration>1 sec</yieldDuration>
            </config>
            <executionNodeRestricted>false</executionNodeRestricted>
            <name>PutS3Object</name>
            <relationships>
                <autoTerminate>false</autoTerminate>
                <name>failure</name>
            </relationships>
            <relationships>
                <autoTerminate>true</autoTerminate>
                <name>success</name>
            </relationships>
            <state>STOPPED</state>
            <style/>
            <type>org.apache.nifi.processors.aws.s3.PutS3Object</type>
        </processors>
    </snippet>
    <timestamp>02/22/2022 13:16:25 IST</timestamp>
</template>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [system requirements for NiFi](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#system_requirements)

In particular, regarding the jdk version `Requires Java 8 or Java 11`.

Let us know if the issue persists after you have met the requirements of NiFi.

Comment: I used JDK 11.0.13 to test the same. I got the same issue even after updating CACERTS with Keytool.

Comment: @JeevaBharathi Please update your question with the version of NiFi you are using, and the config of your PutS3Object (you can obscure the bucket name).

Comment: Added version and configuration details. Thank you.

Comment: @JeevaBharathi Thanks - a screenshot of the PutS3 via the UI is enough :)

Comment: @JeevaBharathi did you find a solution? I'm running into a similar issue trying to connect to wss://

Comment: @LeoReyes Sadly It didn't panout. My team decided to continue using Python and Pandas (to read the db, write the dataframe as parquet file in temp, and write the file to S3)